# how to perform load test of web application that involves user clicking actions

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I need to perform load test on our web application that involves user interaction to the web pages. So i have written selenium scripts to 
handle the click events.For,example we have functionalities like some users has to perform signup/registering to our site,some has to login and perform click actions and logout, and a set of users has to visit our home page, click on multiple URL links available on the home page.
In JMeter,i have added one threadgroup each for above mentioned functionalities.Each threadgroup has "JUnit Request Sampler" which calls the selenium methods that has code for performing click actions.
I have setup the "Thread Properties" for the threadgroups to run 200 threads per minute over a span of 5 to 10 mins[target is for 15 mins]
Default browser i am using is "Firefox".I have also set the JMeter properties such that i wouldn't landup into any memory issues.
I am running the scripts in non-gui mode and collecting the result into a jtl file.
The problem i am facing here is, while scripts are executing multiple browsers openup and as each page involves click events,some of the clicks are not happening correctly resulting in increase in error count. If i use very minimal number of threads with time delay then no errors are seen.
 I have tried with distributed mode testing as well but there was no major reduce in error count.
I am looking forward for a solution or rather suggestions that can help me out to have minimal or zero errors while running JMeter scripts that involves user interactions and achieve intended load or thereafter increase the load. 
Regards
Praveena

Answer (score 0):

As per [WebDriver Tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) it is not recommended to use WebDriver to conduct the load onto the web application

> From experience, the number of browser (threads) that the reader creates should be limited by the following formula:
>
> **C = B + 1**
>
> where C = Number of Cores of the host running the test
>
> and N = Number of Browser (threads).

Looking into [Firefox browser requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/56.0.2/system-requirements/) I strongly doubt you have a computer with 200 cores and 400 GBs of RAM therefore my expectation is that you should use JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to create the load.

Browsers don't do any magic, they send [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render the responses, so well-behaved protocol-based JMeter tests will look just like a real browser for the application under test. So I would recommend [converting your Selenium tests into "pure" JMeter tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter), you can leave 1-2 browsers to measure end-user experience when the application is under the load.